# Gradient descent proof: justify $\left(\dfrac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa + 1}\right)^2 \leq \exp(-\dfrac{4t}{\kappa+1})$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

A claim on pg 279 of the [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4980.pdf) states that:

[image]

How can the encircled be justified? Note that $\kappa := \beta /\alpha$ is a non-negative constant.

I tried using the definition of the exponential:

$$e^z = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+z/n)^n$$ to no avail, because I cannot produce such an $n$ for the term $\left(\dfrac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa + 1}\right)^2$

Can someone please show how this inequality was attained?

Comment: Note that you've got $\| x_{t}-x^{*} \|$ in the first line and $\| x_{1}-x^{*} \|$ in the second line. Apparently the product of the $t$ factors of $(\kappa -1 )/(\kappa +1)$ is less than or equal to $e^{-4t/(\kappa+1)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overlooked that in the last inequality the iterate changes to $1$ from $t$. So the inequality you need is just
\begin{align*}
 \left(\left(1 - \frac {2} {\kappa + 1}  \right)^2 \right)^t \le  \left(e^{ \frac{-4} {\kappa +1} } \right)^t.
\end{align*}
For the remaining part you only need to note
\begin{align*}
\left(1 - \frac {2} {\kappa + 1}  \right)^2 = 1 - \frac{4} {\kappa + 1} + \frac{4}{(\kappa +1 )^2} \\
e^{ \frac{-4} {\kappa +1} } = 1 - \frac{4}{\kappa + 1} + \frac{8}{(\kappa +1)^2} -  \dots \ge 1 - \frac{4} {\kappa + 1} + \frac{4}{(\kappa +1 )^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Aha. But what is the relationship between $\|x_t - x^*\|$ and $\|x_1 - x^*\|$?

Comment: You can apply your second to last inequality repeatedly.